# How do I update a Gridlayout after actionlistener is triggered

Tags: java, swing, jframe, grid-layout

I am trying to build a grid containing a player (red square) that can move around the grid using the WASD keys. So far my actionlistener is registering key pressed, however when calling the repaint() method on the grid (panel), nothing changes. How can I get the board to update?

Here is my Main class:

```
public class game {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame GUI = new GUI();
        GUI.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Here is my custom JFrame:

```
public class GUI extends JFrame implements KeyListener {
    
    //JPanel board = new board();
    public board board;

    public GUI() {
        super();
        board = new board();
        add(board);
        //setSize(800, 800);
        //setVisible(true);

        pack();
        addKeyListener(this);
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void repaint() {
        super.repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        board.keyPressed(e);
        board.repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) { }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) { }
}
```

Here is my custom JPanel class that constructs the grid using JLabels:

```
public class board extends JPanel {

    public static final int GRID_SIZE = 20;

    int playerX = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, GRID_SIZE + 1);
    int playerY = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, GRID_SIZE + 1);

    public board() {

        //JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        int row = GRID_SIZE;
        int col = GRID_SIZE;

        setBounds(100, 100, 500, 500);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(col, row));

        JLabel[][] grid= new JLabel[col][row];
        for (int y = 0; y < col; y++){
            for (int x = 0; x < row; x++){
                grid[x][y] = new JLabel();
                grid[x][y].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
                grid[x][y].setBackground(Color.white);
                grid[x][y].setOpaque(true);
                add(grid[x][y]);
            }
        }
        grid[playerX][playerY].setBackground(Color.red);
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int k = e.getKeyCode();

        switch (k) {
            case KeyEvent.VK_D:
                playerX++;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_A:
                playerX--;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_W:
                playerY--;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_S:
                playerY++;
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/106-java-style-conventions

Answer (score 0):

You have to update the background in your callback.

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int k = e.getKeyCode();
    grid[playerX][playerY].setBackground(Color.WHITE); 
    switch (k) {
        case KeyEvent.VK_D:
            playerX++;
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_A:
            playerX--;
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_W:
            playerY--;
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_S:
            playerY++;
            break;
    }
    grid[playerX][playerY].setBackground(Color.red);
}
```